# Access index.php from docker

Tags: php, docker, symfony, docker-compose

I've created a docker with a database and a php server but I'm failing accessing the php file from the server.

For testing purpose I'm currently having 2 index.php in my test app `./index.php` and `./app/index.php`

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  symfony:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    image: project-manager
    ports:
      - 80:80
  db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    links:
      - db
```

This is the php dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Install Composer
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Copy all our files in the docker root
COPY . /
```

`docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
f80a16af8336        project-manager         "docker-php-entrypoi…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 9000/tcp        project-manager_symfony_1
d97688010adf        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   9 minutes ago        Up 9 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp                project-manager_phpmyadmin_1
55781c004031        mysql                   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   9 minutes ago        Up 9 minutes        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   project-manager_db_1
```

In my `/etc/hosts`

```
#Project Manager
127.0.0.1 project-manager.local
```

I can successfully access to the phpmyadmin using `project-manager.local:8080`

But if I try the simple `project-manager.local/` or `project-manager.local/index`
I've got an empty response.

Comment: There is no php container in your docker-compose file

Comment: The `docker/Dockerfile` is the dockerfile I put in the issue, if I connect to this one php is well installed on the container. But may be I need to specify something to launch the server actually ? But what bother me the most is that once i'm connected to the f80a16af8336 container...the index.php is missing. I only have an empty /var/www/html folder

Comment: Two of your containers expose port 80, this alone cannot work...

Comment: you are copying your files to the root of the container `/` so your `index.php` file is at the root in the container and you would see it doing `ls /`

Comment: Indeed @Nathanael thanks. So now I just have to figure out how to get the php work :)

Comment: @LarsStegelitz I don't understand what you mean. I bind my 80 to the 80 symfony docker container. And I bind my 8080 to the 80 of the phpmyadmin container. As they aren't the same container it shouldn't be an issue they have the same port right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Root cause:**

For `symfony`, you bind `80:80`, this means you suppose there is a port `80` open in the php container. But, you use `php:7.4-fpm` which will just open [port 9000](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/0274f58b8dcf68a23d8fd77101d2d4c74d38fc65/7.4/buster/fpm/Dockerfile#L258).

(If you install `net-tools` in the container & use `netstat -oanltp` to check, there won't be `80` port open.)

**Solutions:**

***Option 1:***

If you insist to use `php-fpm`, then you need another `web server container` to pass the `80 request` to `php container`'s `9000` port. Maybe could add a more service with [nginx container](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx), and refers to [connecting-nginx-to-php-fpm](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/#connecting-nginx-to-php-fpm) to set your configure for nginx container:

```
fastcgi_pass symfony:9000;
```

***Option 2:***

Switch to use `php:7.4-apache`, which defaults has a web server in the image open the `80` port, like next:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
COPY . /var/www/html
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

NOTE: you should copy files to `/var/www/html`.

**In a word,** you should assure the container which you expose `80:80` really have a port `80` open in the container, otherwise, your expose is useless...

Comment: Any idea what might cause a 403 forbidden access once the container is setup with php:7.4-apache ? EDIT : My bad wwas just on the wrong path :) All good.